# System exception handling on different platforms

Tags: c++, exception, signals

Basically, how to catch exceptions on mac/linux? That is, exceptions, that are not intrinsic to the language, like segfaults & integer division. Compiling on MSVC, __try __except is perfect because the stack handling allows to catch exceptions and continue execution lower down the stack.

Now, i would like to extend my program to other platforms (mainly the ones mentioned), but i have no idea how exception handling works on these platforms work. As far as i understand, it's handled through posix signals? And as of such, wont allow to handle exception and continue lower down the stack?

Edit: Would this be valid (pseudo code)? As i see it, i leave C++ blocks correctly and thus dont indulge myself in UB.

```
jmp_buf buffer;

template< typename func >
    protected_code(func f) {
        if(!setjmp(buffer) {
            f();        
        } 
        else
        {
            throw std::exception("exception happened in f()"):
        }
    }


void sig_handler()  {
    longjmp(buffer);
}

int main() {
    sigaction(sig_handler);

    try {

        protected_code( [&] 
            {
                1/0;
            }
        );
    }
    catch(const std::exception & e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Wow for some reason i never thought of just throwing a C++ exception from the signal handler, no need to use longjmp/setjmp then. It of course relies on the fact that the thread calling the signal handler is the same stack and thread that faulted. Is this defined/guaranteed somewhere?
Code example:

```
void sig_handler(int arg) {
    throw 4;
}

int main() {

    signal(SIGFPE, sig_handler);

    try {
        int zero = 1;
        zero--;
        int ret = 1/zero;
    } catch(int x) {
        printf("catched %d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Unix, you'd catch processor faults with signal handlers, using the [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) function to install a suitable handler for the `signal` that you want to handle.

(I think you mean `__try ... __except` rather than `__try ... __catch`.

Comment: Yeah i did. Okay thanks for the info, is it safe/legal to longjmp out of the signal handler to a lower point of execution?

Comment: Trying to "continue" after exceptions in Unix OS's is generally not a great thing to do. What are you actually trying to do? Why are there exceptions in the first place? Yes, you can use `longjmp` to get back, but bear in mind that it you may find undefined behaviour if you are unlucky...

Comment: You don't explain why you need to do this. Correctly written code should not divide by zero. Check for zero, write an error. Handling this through signals is a clumsy and poor way. And at least some exceptions can leave the system in an undefined state. (Note that I'm not necessarily talking of UB in terms of C or C++, but rather that the process as a whole is "undefined").

Comment: I agree it's not a pretty way, but coding practices aside, is it legal (bearing in mind i can guarantee safety of execution after the exception)? I can explain why but it's a lengthy discussion and not really relevant to the question.

Comment: The short answer is that it't not guaranteed that your system is in a safe state, no. From a C or C++ perspective it MAY be (depends on what is happening, and where your exception happens - e.g. if you are inside a destructor, constructor, locked section), but from a whole system perspective, there are more things to care about.

Comment: As noted in the comments, the code run from the protected_code point has to be pure c (no exceptions, no ctors etc.). I use it to catch floating point exceptions, which per default is disabled, so it's safe to continue.

Comment: Your original post mentions `segfault` as well, and that can certainly cause problems. I believe FP excpetions are safe as long as you don't try to use the results from failed calculations.

Comment: Yeah it was just examples. How about throwing exceptions from the signal handler (see edit)?

Comment: You should definitely use `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp`, when using these from a signal. That will ensure that the signal handling is saved/restored from to the state it was earlier. You also can't rely on destructors behaving as they should (or being called correctly) for automatic objects created between `sigsetjmp` and the `throw`. Dangerous ground, I'd say.

Comment: Yeah.. But the problem is i can't have globals, which means i have to somehow attach the jmp_buf to some thread storage, since signalhandlers cant be passed user defined parameters..